# create-react-app install devDepencies in dependencies section

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After creating a new project with `create-react-app` and running `yarn eject`.

The dependencies section of my package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    etc.
```

I would say these are all `devDependencies` why has create-react-app placed them here?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is an intentional change in one of the latest versions.

The distinction is pretty arbitrary for front-end apps that produce static bundles. Technically you don't need *any* of these dependencies on the server, not even the runtime ones. So by that logic even `react` might be seen as a development dependency.

We used to try to separate them but as explained above, it isn't really consistent in the first place. There's no technical reason why this distinction is useful for apps that have no Node runtime. In addition, it used to cause problems for some Heroku deployments that didn't install development dependencies (and thus weren't able to build the project on the server or test it right before deployment).

In the end we went with just putting everything into dependencies. If you disagree you can always rearrange `package.json` as you deem reasonable.

Comment: But does this not mean that all the devDependencies end up in the production build and get deployed with the app code?  Increasing package size

Comment: > There's no technical reason why this distinction is useful for apps that have no Node runtime.

devDeps and deps run in two totally separate environments, and keeping the two isolated can communicate/document which deps are running in the wild and which are running in CI/trusted environments.  This is extremely helpful for assessing security vulns when they come up.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob - but in this case how does the build step know not to ship Jest (etc) in the final distributable?

Comment: The build systems when generating a prod bundle will construct a graph of dependencies used with your main file. It should not incorporate jest or other build tools as long as there is no direct import of it somewhere in the graph.

Comment: hey @soumitra, but in the case of @ types, imports exist in our code for typing.

So, are they still removed from the production bundle? Is this served for the client (browser)?

Comment: types are removed by the build system when typescript code is compiled, all typescript code converts to js code at build time. You can put all @types/* dependencies in dev dependencies.

Comment: [5.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app/v/5.0.1) was move to dependencies

Comment: i am a bit sad because of this inconsistency by create-react-app. I hope this is changed in the future.

Comment: Time proved that it was wrong decision.

Comment: @Drag13 and why is that? have any sources to share on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

These are all dev dependencies if the app you are building is a library, that you want to publish others to use.

Basically my understanding is this, if you have a module that can be used in two ways:

- Consumed via `npm i`
- Developed via cloning the project

In that scenario, it makes sense to put them in dev dependencies.

In your case people are going to clone your project to develop. And consume it via hosted one.

Hope this helps.!