# How do I decide whether @types/* goes into `dependencies` or `devDependencies`?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, package.json

I use TypeScript 2 in my project. I'd like to use some js library, but also typings for that library. I can install types with simple `npm install @types/some-library`. I'm not sure if I should `--save` or `--save-dev` them. It seems to me that even DefinetelyTyped GitHub readme kind of mentions both versions, but never explains them. I would think that @types should be in `devDependencies`, as types are needed for development and aren't used in runtime, but I saw many times @types in just `dependencies`. I'm confused.

How should I decide whether @types/* goes into `dependencies` or `devDependencies`? Are there actually some more or less official instructions?

Comment: Are you generating a bundle or is this a package that will be used by others? As I see it you only need to make the distinction between `dependencies` and `devDependencies` in the latter case.

Comment: I make some game in js/ts from scratch. I bundle everything with webpack. There's no backend at all atm, but it's possible that I'll wrap it all in Electron to make it standalone some day. I don't think anyone will ever use it as a dependency in their own app, but I guess it could be possible (think of mini games in GTA games; and my game is open source). Still, I want to learn and follow best practices and it's the main reason I make that game. I hope I clarified my use-case well enough. :)

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, just wanted to make sure that my original answer was relevant to your use case. I still think that the distinction between `devDependencies` and `dependencies` is irrelevant when building a bundle, it's something that `create-react-app` enforces [as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872787/1333383) but ultimately it's up to you to choose

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Let's say you're developing a package "A" that have `@types/some-module` package in `devDependencies`. For some reason you're exporting the type from `@types/some-module`:

```
import { SomeType } from 'some-module';

export default class APackageClass {
  constructor(private config: SomeType) {
    // …       
  }
}
```

Right now TypeScript consumers of package "A" are unable to guess what `SomeType` is, since `devDependencies` of package "A" are **not** installed.

In that particular case you **need** to place `@types/*` package with regular `dependencies`. For other cases `devDependencies` are good enough.

Comment: So you imply that, if I only use the type in implementation, it’s type definition can be `devDependencies`?

Comment: Yes @FranklinYu . As soon as the type appears in declaration file, you need to place it on `dependencies`. Otherwise `devDependencies` is fine

Comment: But a package works for both TS and JS. JS developers doesn't need those types to compile their code. Adding the type definition to `dependencies` will make dependency tree bloated.

Comment: @TylerLong Correct. It's not perfect but that's reality. Optionally You can also use "optionalDependencies" but I believe at scale it might be very annoying.

Comment: I suppose that in case I'm developing an end-user application and not a package I can move all the @types/.. into the devDependencies, correct?

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno I think so. As long as your application builds properly in the environment that builds it, then you're good. Whether your build environment installs devDependencies before building, and whether it needs those to build your code, may differ depending on your situation but is easy to test and find out.

Comment: @wookieb Is the code snippet you provided a declaration file or a normal .ts file? It seems to contain implementation that's why I asked. It also seems it is a declaration file due to this sentence "For some reason you're exporting the type from @types/some-module...."

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava it is a regulars ts file. But once it is compiled to .d.ts file the file would still contain import and reference to a type.


`import { SomeType } from 'some-module';
export default class APackageClass {
constructor(private config: SomeType){}
}
`

Comment: @wookieb in your comment if that's a .d.ts file, the constructor should be without `{}` no? I also thought your original code snippet in the answer was .d.ts, maybe because of this sentence "For some reason you're exporting the type from @types/some-module..."

Comment: Yes without `{}`.

You're not exporting the type explicitly but using it in the code and compiling to .d.ts cause the type name to exist in .d.ts file therefore every consumer of the package needs to resolve import of it.

Answer (score 93):

If you're just generating a bundle there may be no need to make the distinction between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. This feature of `npm` is generally useful when publishing a package that can be used by others and you don't want to spam them with redundant dependencies.

There may be other use cases where splitting dependencies can be helpful but unless you have an express need for this, then my advice is to just pick either one and place everything there. It's not difficult to split them afterwards if the need should arise.

A well-known example of this practice IRL is `create-react-app`, by default the un-ejected boilerplate it creates places everything in `dependencies`, see [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4342) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872787/1333383)

Comment: If you're not publishing the package, that's correct, but if you are, it has nothing to do with development vs. runtime and everything with *what's needed to build this package* vs. *what's needed to use this package*.

Comment: @Yogu That's why I made the distinction in the first place so yes, I completely agree with you

Comment: I disagree with this advice. `devDependencies` are not installed when you do `npm install --production` (or `npm ci --production`) and thus not available when running production code. This is a very meaningful difference for a service, not just a library.

Comment: @BradWilson You have a point, there are many npm workflows under the sun, if your use case requires you to make the distinction then by all means, do it. Feel free to provide your own answer to this dilemma.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mention the existence of other use cases where the distinction may be meaningful and gave real world examples. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It depends on the stack. For example, I think when working with NextJS, using `devDependencies` is important for bundle size

Comment: How is this relevant, considering the original question does not make mention of any bundling?

Answer (score 49):

In the particular case of deploying a Node.js application to production, one wants to install only the dependencies needed to run the application.

`npm install --omit=dev` or

`npm ci --production` or

`yarn --production`

In that case, the types should be in the `devDependencies`, to keep them from bloating the installation.

(To avoid misunderstandings, the `--production` or `--omit=dev` option must not be used on machines where the application is built, otherwise the TypeScript compiler will complain.)

*Remarks: I'm aware this was mentioned in a comment by Brad Wilson to another answer. This point seems worthy to be an answer, though.*

Comment: I am developing an app using 3rd party libs, put all of the @types/* packages in devDependencies, but then production build fails as typescript is looking for these types in the production build.

Comment: @omerts: When you wrote "looking for these types in the production build", did you mean "looking for these types in the package.json during compilation"? I'm asking because a production build is what's run on the target machine, and it would be strange if the TypeScript compiler were invoked at that stage. If on the other hand you were talking about compilation on a _developer_ machine, the `devDependencies` should still exist at that stage, because `--production` should only be used when installing for production - not on the developer machine.

Comment: When running yarn/npm install with the production flag on, and then yarn build, either in a CI or docker env, the typescript compiler will fail due to missing types.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you use the `--production` option already on machines where the application is built. Instead, the option should be used only on machines where the application is run, not built. I clarified my main answer in that regard.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, why would you want to run npm/yarn install on machines where the application is only run?

Comment: @omerts While it is sometimes possible to copy the node modules from the build machine the hosts (i.e. the machines that run the application), this seems like a questionable practice, because: Even if the Node.js version number on the hosts is identical to that of the build machine, the target machines might be a different OS. For example, you may develop on Windows, but run things on Linux. And there are cases where e.g. the output of `npm install` on Windows is not correct on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "must not be used on machines where the application is built, otherwise the TypeScript compiler will complain", what is the point if the code is not for built, I guess you are refer to `npm` packages that is consumed directly by others.

Comment: @windmaomao I thought about your comment and realized: My own answer does not make sense to me anymore. (It definitely made sense to me when I wrote it in 2019, but I can't remember the exact circumstances.) I will soon remove this answer. I'll just keep it a little bit to enable reactions.

Comment: I found no way of deleting my own answer here, probably because of the upvotes. Maybe it really did help people somehow...

Answer (score 2):

Depending what will your code be used for. If you need the types in your production code (e.g: if you create a custom package that re-export the types), then it should be in `dependencies`, otherwise if it's for development purpose only, `devDependencies` is the right place to put them in.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers made great sense, but I'm gonna add that a peerDep's type declaration package should also be placed in `dependencies` instead of `peerDependencies`.

Assume that `b` is a plugin of `a`. And `c` uses `a` and `b`.

Why shouldn't `@types/a` be placed in `b`'s `peerDependencies`?

If `b`'s `package.json` is like:

```json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "a": "1.5.x"
    "@types/a": "1.4.x"
  }
}
```

`c` may use only interfaces defined in `@types/a@1.2.x` but `c` is forced to install `@types/a@1.4.x`.

Furthermore, `c` may be a regular javascript package rather than typescript package, but `c` is also forced to install `@types/a@1.4.x`.

So, the correct `package.json` of `b` should be like:

```json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "a": "1.5.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/a": "1.4.x"
  }
}
```