# Why do people store typescript's types as dependency in package.json (instead of devDep)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies, package.json

I noticed in almost all tutorials or blog posts about typescript, people just install packages via npm for types and/or typescript related modules as dependency.
This is compile-time related thing and end user will never have to load this, so for me logically this should all be impl. detail and thus go to devDependecies part of package.json.
I'm assuming that I'm missing something and would like the compact yet reasonable answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While this was my standing back in '17 when this was written, I was shown evidence to the contrary. See the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176661/how-do-i-decide-whether-types-goes-into-dependencies-or-devdependencies) for more details.

---

<s>Because they are lazy/ignorant of the difference.</s>

`@types` should definitely be `devDependencies`, you don't want them installed when you `npm i some-package`, only when you clone the code and call `npm i`.

You are completely right.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. There are definitely scenarios where `npm i some-package` should pull down types, as discussed in the (correct) answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176661/how-do-i-decide-whether-types-goes-into-dependencies-or-devdependencies?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ChrisArnesen What if your package has a type dependency that's not required for an end user application to build, but is useful for the end developer to have while development? I know that it should go to "dependencies" because there is no other option, and production will now also include the types. But I want to know why isn't there something like "typeDependencies" for such occasions? It'd install for the end user while developing, but not in production mode.

Comment: I like the idea of `typeDependencies` too, and we're not the only ones https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/582#issuecomment-411519423 . I bet there's an issue somewhere in the TypeScript source code repository discussing the possibility. If anyone finds such an issue, please post a link here.