# When authoring a TypeScript library, what is the best practice for a package that depends on @types/nodejs? Should you set them as a peerDependency?

Tags: typescript

I am authoring a library that supports a minimum node version of 16. The library consumes and exports Node types from the `@types/node@^16.0.0` package.

I haven't included the node types in my package's dependencies so when consumers install the package, they don't have the types.

[image: image showing missing types node types from type declaration in node_modules]

Given I am specifying a particular node version (latest minor version of Node 16 types), I would imagine that I would want to set that as a `dependency`.

Would that cause collisions if there are other versions of `@types/node` in the consuming project?

Should it be a `peerDependency`? In that case, what if the types don't match the ones in my library and that causes compilation errors?

Comment: You should define your dependencies

Comment: NPM doesn't really have an idea of "peer dev dependencies". If a consumer is using your package from TypeScript and a supported Node version, they'll likely already have installed @types/node. If they're using JS they don't need to get errors about missing peer deps for types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I decide whether @types/\* goes into \`dependencies\` or \`devDependencies\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176661/how-do-i-decide-whether-types-goes-into-dependencies-or-devdependencies)